# What does order means here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Actually *Jim* came to *Sister Ana* for know about Johnny who grew up near her, So She showed him photos of Johnny.

> *Jim*: This is Johnny. He looks so happy.
>
> *Sister Ana*: He should. That's sister Julie(in photo). His Physics teacher.
>
> *Jim*: I always liked Physics.
>
> *Sister Ana*: So did Johnny. He disgraced sister Julie who had to leave
>   the **order**.

What does order means here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough context to be sure, but, since they address each other as "Sister Ana" and "Sister Julie" I guess that [religious order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_order) may be implied.

Check out [this definition from dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/order):

> 23. a body or society of persons living by common consent under the same religious, moral, or social regulations.

I suspect that Johnny did something that forced sister Julie to leave her congregation/monastery/social group. See if that makes sense in a broader context.